# Google Sheets - Code to send an email to an address in a cell upon selection of a dropdown menu cell

Tags: email, google-sheets

I know very little about code and am simply looking for help if someone knows how to do this. I have a google spreadsheet and for this example let's say

Column A is an email address 
Column B is text
Column C is a dropdown list of items made using the Data Validation tool (pending, scheduled and complete).

I need a code that upon selecting "Complete" in column C, an email is sent to the recipient in column A with the body of the email containing the text from column B.

Any help is appreciated as I'm not a developer, I'm a pastor trying to help my church run more smooth.

and here's the link to the spreadsheet...  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bA-gDvZ_jbJMyU6IqExBjHKclrKmqJSMHyuKHsr2CMA/edit?usp=sharing

and here's the script...

```
    var sheetname = "FacilitiesWorkRequests";

function onOpen() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetname);
  var range = sheet.getRange(1, 3, sheet.getLastRow(), 1);
  var list = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(["pending", "scheduled", "complete"], true).build();
  range.setDataValidation(list);
}

function onEdit() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetname);
  var ac = sheet.getActiveCell();
  if (ac.getValue() == "complete") {
    data = sheet.getRange(ac.getRowIndex(), 1, 1, 2).getValues();
    Logger.log(data)
    MailApp.sendEmail({
      to: data[0][0],
      subject: "sample mail",
      body: data[0][1]
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this sample?

```
var sheetname = "Here, please input your sheet name.";

function onOpen() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetname);
  var range = sheet.getRange(1, 3, sheet.getLastRow(), 1);
  var list = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(["pending", "scheduled", "complete"], true).build();
  range.setDataValidation(list);
}

function onEdit() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetname);
  var ac = sheet.getActiveCell();
  if (ac.getValue() == "complete") {
    data = sheet.getRange(ac.getRowIndex(), 1, 1, 2).getValues();
    Logger.log(data)
    MailApp.sendEmail({
      to: data[0][0],
      subject: "sample mail",
      body: data[0][1]
    });
  }
}
```

[image]

Please copy and paste this script to the script editor on spreadsheet, and set a sheet name you use, and then install a trigger. How to install a trigger is as follows. You can see the detailed information of this at https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#google_apps_triggers.

1. At the script editor, choose "Resources" - "Current project's triggers".
2. Click "here" and add a trigger.
3. Under Run, select the function of "onEdit()".
4. Event is "From spreadsheet" - "Change of value".

For this sample script, when you open spreadsheet with this script, the dropdown list is applied, while the existing dropdown list is not changed. Because if you had added new row, new dropdown list is added. When you run this script, if authentication screen appears, please authenticate it.

And when you choose "complete" from the dropdown list, an e-mail is sent using e-mail of same row you chose. E-mail body is column B of same row.

If this will be helpful, I'm glad.

Comment: Thanks! Now what if I want to change the columns. In my actual spreadsheet, the email address is in column L, body text will be in G and the drop down field will be column J. So how do I change that? I'm not seeing column headers in this code.

Comment: Column is defined by "getRange()". Document of "getRange()" is here. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer) "onOpen()" makes a dropdown list. "onEdit()" send an e-mail.

Comment: Thank you. I understand now. however I keep getting this error. 

TypeError: Cannot call method "getActiveCell" of null. (line 12, file "Code")

Comment: Can I ask you about the current script and sheet? I cannot understand about line 12. I'm sorry. Please add the current script and sheet on your main question using EDIT button. If your sheet is included personal information, please add a sample sheet.

Comment: I've added a link to my spreadsheet and the script for you to see @Tanaike

Comment: The error I kept getting was referring to line 12 in the script: 

var ac = sheet.getActiveCell();

Comment: The sheet name if "EMF Form". In my browser, it seems like "EMF Form". If it's "EMF Form", please change to var sheetname = "EMF Form". Also I confirmed that the name can be included some spaces. The document of "getSheetByName()" is here. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getSheetByName(String)